# How to copy image file from my desktop to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, static-files

I have a profile page in my app which I am migrating to docker. I want to have a default profile picture for user who don't upload any picture for that I need to store that picture in my container.

I have my default profile pic stored at data/web/media/default.jpg and want it to copy to vol/web/media/default.jpg in my docker container.

I tried COPY but got this error

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/data" not found: not found

**My dockerfile :**

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="mRk"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY ./data /vol

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg && \
    pip install Pillow && \
    apk del build-deps && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    cp ./data/web/media/default.jpg /vol/web/media/default.jpg && \
    chown -R app:app /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER app

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

**My docker-compose file :**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      - EMAIL_USER=${EMAIL_USER}
      - EMAIL_PASS=${EMAIL_PASS}
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}

  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
```

Comment: Post the file listing as well from the folder where your docker-compose.yml is

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help us pin-point the exact issue. Here you posted the entire project.

Comment: `failed to compute cache key: "..." not found: not found` indicates you that the folder `data` does not exists. Are you sure that you are in the correct folder when running your build command and that the folder `data` does exists in your host in this "correct" folder?

Answer (score 0):

This line isn't going to work since you set your `WORKDIR` to `/app/` earlier.

```
cp ./data/web/media/default.jpg /vol/web/media/default.jpg && \
```

You have to change your working directory or use an absolute path

An other solution would be to put this line below the `RUN` command since you don't need to be in the `/app/` directory to run it:

```
WORDIR = /app/
```

Comment: That's true, but it is not what is failing for the OP at the moment, the error states the build fail on a `COPY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to copy something from the `data` dir:

```
cp ./data/web/media/default.jpg /vol/web/media/default.jpg && \
```

But this directory does not exist. However, you copied everything from the `data` dir on your host machine into your container dir `vol` on line:

```
COPY ./data /vol
```

That means, that all your files and dirs from `data` or copied into the `vol` dir in the container. So I geuss you do not need that line at all, as it is already in your container but in the `vol` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker volumes which help you to copy and read files from docker

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/